# External Files in Python - Not writing to the external file properly

Tags: python, python-3.6

I can't get my program to work right. I have 2D lists that are created from user input. After all the user input, the 2D lists are supposed to write to an external file and it is giving me an error.

```
outfile = open("food.txt","a")
for foo in menu:
  outfile.write(",".join(foo) + "\n")
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Please do the following: provide the error you get, fix or remove the link (it is useless right now).

Comment: Can you add the code for receiving the input from the user?

Comment: Please, add the content of `menu`. Try to print it on the screen before writing it to the file, just to be sure that is created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

did you try creating a new file with?

```
outfile = open("food.txt","w")
```

> EDIT:

**Please share more information on how you create your list.**

Your code is running properly with 1D list of strings:

```
menu = ['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber']
outfile = open("food.txt","a")
for foo in menu:
  outfile.write(",".join(foo) + "\n")
outfile.close()
```

Content of `food.txt`:

```
a,p,p,l,e
b,a,n,a,n,a
c,u,c,u,m,b,e,r
```

Comment: Yes, the file is creating but nothing is writing to it.

Comment: please provide more information on how menu is created or what the content is before passing it to your code snippet.